# tclhttpd.3.5.1 shows page source  (Windows)

Tags: http-headers, tcl

I am playing with tclhttpd web server and found a strange error

1. I start tclhttpd at default port 8015
2. Open firefox and navigate to  http://localhost:8015

I see source of my index.html file instead of web page.

index.html is simple ( < and > are skipped ):

```
  html 
  head 
    title
      TEST 
    /title
  /head
  body
   H1 TEST HEADER /H1
  /body
  /html
```

Any ideas?

I have checked  with the curl:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 8015 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8015 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.3 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.21.3 
  OpenSSL/0.9.8q zlib/1.2.5
> Host: localhost:8015
> Accept: */*
```

Server Response

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 Data follows
 Date: Thu, 12 Apr 2012 14:16:47 GMT
 Server: Tcl-Webserver/3.5.1 May 27, 2004
 Content-Type: text/plain
 Content-Length: 130
 Last-Modified: Thu, 12 Apr 2012 14:14:30 GMT
```

So, tclhttpd returns text/plain instead of text/html

**Linux case**

I have tried to check what would happened with Linux.

As tclkttpd is wrapped in kit I made the same test under Linux.
It looks like everything works fine.

curl -G -v localhost:8015

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 8015 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8015 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.7 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.7
  OpenSSL/1.0.0d zlib/1.2.5 libssh2/1.2.7
> Host: localhost:8015
> Accept: */*
```

Server response

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 Data follows
 Date: Thu, 12 Apr 2012 17:25:29 GMT
 Server: Tcl-Webserver/3.5.1 May 27, 2004
 Content-Type: text/html
 Content-Length: 125
 Last-Modified: Thu, 12 Apr 2012 17:14:04 GMT
```

**Deep research**

I have modified some of the source files, to dump more information:

```
proc Mtype {path} {
   global MimeType

    set ext [string tolower [file extension $path]]
    Stderr "Mtype: path $path ext $ext"
    if {[info exist MimeType($ext)]} {
    Stderr "MimeType($ext) exists."
    Stderr "Print MimeType "
    set lst [lsort [array names MimeType]]
    foreach {i}  $lst {
        Stderr " $i $MimeType($i)"
    }
return $MimeType($ext)
  } else {
Stderr "Mimetype not found. ext $ext"
    Stderr "Print MimeType "
    set lst [lsort [array names MimeType]]
    foreach {i}  $lst {
        Stderr " $i $MimeType($i)"
    }

return text/plain
}
}
```

When I query http://localhost:8015
I got following output:

- Linux

```
     Mtype: path /home/a2/src/tcl/tcl_www/doc/index.html ext .html
     MimeType(.html) exists.
     Print MimeType 
     text/plain
     .ai application/postscript
     .aif audio/x-aiff
     .aifc audio/x-aiff
     ....
     .hqx application/mac-binhex40
     .htm text/html
     .html text/html
     .i86pc application/octet-stream
     ...
     Default cmd Doc_text/html
```

- Windows

```
     Look for Tcl proc whos name match the MIME Content-Type
     Mtype: path M:/apr/tcl_www/doc/index.html ext .html
     Mimetype not found. ext .html
     Print MimeType
      .man application/x-doctool
     Mtype M:/apr/tcl_www/doc/index.html  returns Doc_text/plain
```

So it look like there are troubles with reading mime.types

Comment: What happens if you access the index.html directly?

Comment: @alexvetter nothing. The same result.

Comment: `Doc_text/plain` is obviously incorrect as it uses "text/html" for the `$type` parameter instead of "text/plain".

Comment: No, he tries to set the mimetype by hand. Even if `Doc_text/plain` is called by `tclhttpd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked with the fresh tclkitsh and tclhttpd

- tclkitsh-8.5.9-win32.upx.exe ( http://code.google.com/p/tclkit/downloads/list )
- tclhttpd5.3.1.kit

Everything works.

If I use my "old" version of tclkitsh-win32.upx.exe
 I receive **text/plain** instead of **text/html**

So it looks like there is a bug in my old wrapped interpretor, that leads to the problem with not reading mime.types.

Answer (score 1):

You have to inspect the traffic tclhttpd generates to see if it really says in the HTTP headers of its response that the payload type is "text/html".

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), [sockspy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sockspy/), [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://blogs.technet.com/b/netmon/p/downloads.aspx) or [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org).

Also there are lighter-weight debugging tools for browsers. I'm pretty sure [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) wold show you this information, and even simple [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) can do that.

IE also has some debugging addon (akin to Firebug) which I'm lazy to google for.

Comment: Maybe add [sockspy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sockspy/) to the list of tools.

Comment: @kostix I have checked html trafix with HttpFox (If I am not mistaken) Server returns correct text/html header. Any ideas?

Comment: @kostix I have checked it with the CURL. it returns text/plain.  Any Idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Problem found.

httpdthread.tcl

```
# Core modules
package require httpd           ;# Protocol stack
package require httpd::version  ;# Version number
package require httpd::url  ;# URL dispatching
package require httpd::mtype    ;# Mime types

# Search for mime.types either right in Config(lib), or down
# one level in the installed tclhttpd subdirectory
foreach path [list \
    [file join $Config(lib) mime.types] \
    [glob -nocomplain [file join $Config(lib) tclhttpd* mime.types]] \
    ] {
    if {[llength $path] > 0} {
        set path [lindex $path 0]
       }
    if {[file exists $path]} {
      Mtype_ReadTypes $path
      break
    }
}
```

This code checks for the mime.types file under following paths:
  - /home/a2/..../tclhttpd3.5.1.kit/bin/../lib
  - /home/a2/..../tclhttpd3.5.1.kit/bin/../lib/tclhttpd*/mime.types

**Linux**

```
glob -nocomplain /home/..../tclhttpd3.5.1.kit/bin/../lib/tclhttpd*/mime.types]
```

works fine and returns

```
/home/....tclhttpd3.5.1.kit/bin/../lib/tclhttpd3.5.1/mime.types
```

**Windows**

```
 glob -nocomplain /home/..../tclhttpd3.5.1.kit/bin/../lib/tclhttpd*/mime.types]
```

failed.

I have tried different masks:

- tclhttpd*
- tclhttpd*.*
- tclhttpd*.*.*

nothing is working

Finally I have modified the code:

```
foreach path [list \
    [file join $Config(lib) mime.types] \
    [glob -nocomplain [file join $Config(lib) tclhttpd* mime.types]] \
    [file join $Config(lib) [lindex [Httpd_Version] 0] mime.types] 
    ] {
    if {[llength $path] > 0} {
        set path [lindex $path 0]
       }
    if {[file exists $path]} {
      Mtype_ReadTypes $path
      break
    }
}
```

string

```
[file join $Config(lib) [lindex [Httpd_Version] 0] mime.types]
```

generate the path:

```
/home/..../tclhttpd3.5.1.kit/bin/../lib/tclhttpd3.5.1/mime.types
```

Now tclhttpd could find mime.types under windows.

And it looks like that problem happened only if **glob** is searching inside the statkit file.

Comment: @kostix Thanks for cooperation. Any ideas why glob did not work properly from the startkit file?

Comment: @alexvetter Thanks for cooperation. Any ideas why glob did not work properly from the startkit file?

Answer (score 0):

I think `tclhttpd` automatically uses `text/html` if the file ends with `.html`. You properly should read [this wiki entry on `wiki.tcl.tk` about mime-type](http://wiki.tcl.tk/12736).

Tried it myself with a `index.html` and it worked. Than I created an `index.tml` and it worked.

```
[html::description "Test"]
[Doc_Dynamic]
[html::head "hello"]
<body>
test
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the header part of the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Data follows
Content-Length: 137
Date: Thu, 12 Apr 2012 16:47:53 GMT
Server: Tcl-Webserver/3.5.1 May 27, 2004
Connection: Close
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: I would expect it. Actually the only file I have called index.html So everything should be ok?

Comment: Could you try to create an `.tml` and check the result?

Comment: With template file it works. Curl returns text/html and Firefox shows correct page. The question is whz it did not work for the static file?

Comment: I could not recreate the problem. Couldn't you just use pseudo dynamic files. :-)

Comment: Potentially yes. But would be interesting to know the source of the problem. I have played with few web templates and time to time they we shown correctly and time to time not. So it looks like something strange goes on. Would be nice to clear it.

Comment: Actually what is your version of windows/FF? Do you use tclhttpd.kit? Another case could be that it is related to the tcl interpretor (I use wrapped one tclkitsh-win32

Comment: No, I downloaded the current version from `http://www.beedub.com/tclhttpd/`and used the tclsh which comes with Mac OS (tcl 8.5). I tried it with Chromium (Build 131297), Chrome 18, Firefox 11 and Safari 5.1.5. I also used the application HTTP Client and curl.

Comment: Then it should work. I do not have troubles under Linux. Only under Windows (XP)

Comment: Oh, okay. Sorry, but than I can't help you. I only have OS X and W7.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for `curl` getting `text/plain` instead of `text/html` might be that it passes `*/*` in the `Accept` header of its HTTP requests, while typically browsers place some more elaborate construct there—for instance, my FF 11.0 uses `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`.

One might notice that in the FF's case `text/html` (along with XHTML and XML types) is assigned a higher preference (0.9) and everything else (`*/*`) is assigned a lower preference (0.8).

A conformant HTTP server should attempt to serve the requested resource in a format indicated as preferred in the client's request.

Probably that might also shed some light on that original IE vs FF behavioral difference.

Comment: It seams to me that IE show it correctly as it process content additionally.  As you could see from my extended post, if I reconfigure server to the port 8080 (default  proxy) then FF managed to correctly show the page, despite the fact that curl still report text/plain type

Comment: Okay, one more thought: what if you install the [Clear Cache](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clearcache/) addon and retry "normal" request in FF after clearing its caches?  Another option would be to start FF with its `-ProfileManager` [command-line option](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) and continuing with pristine profile.  The basic idea is that I did see issues with browsers "latching" on some cached contents.

Comment: Have checked with FF and Clear Cache. Did not work. The same html code on the  page. The problem is somehow related to the way tclhttpd handle mime types under windows. Look like the only way is to check source code and try to patch it